# what flags will improve gcc/clang compile times?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction

What flags for either gcc or clang will improve compile times? I require debugging to be enabled but any other features are free to be disabled if they will result in faster compiles.

I know there are numerous other ways to improve compile times but I am interested soley in this area.

Comment: that's the best you can hope to do as far as speeding up compilation times from twiddling with flags. There are no flags that will just *magically* make compile times faster. You'll have to look into other ways of improving build times.

Comment: Waving white flags might help. Also, -c or -E are definitely known to improve compile times. In all cases: show us some code and we can begin to hint on ways to improve build times.

Answer (score 6):

The largest gain in compile time is found by eliminating the most work done by the compiler - usually optimisation. So, don't enable optimisation (`-O`) flags.

Comment: Adding -O0 did not help. Right now I use these flags: -g3 -O0 -Wfatal-errors -Wall -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-unused-function -Wall -W -Wwrite-strings -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -ffast-math -Wno-missing-declarations

Comment: Adding -O0 is doing exactly what Greg said to do. It is disabling optimization.

Comment: Adding -O0 when I did not have any -O flags to begin with did not seem to have any effect. I see I made a mistake above, 'right now' should not have included -O0.

Comment: Yes, the default (at least for gcc) is the lack of a `-O` flag means no optimisations are enabled. Note that if you wanted us to provide specific recommendations to change your compiler command line, you probably should have provided your compiler command line in the *question*.

Comment: I can see that you are trying to justify your answer. That is fine, I am interested in a more detailed overview of the possible flags to use, hopefully more than just -O. If there are no other flags, so be it, but if there are then that is what I would consider a sufficient answer. Let me put it this way: start from no flags at all, now what flags can you add to speed up the compile?

Comment: I would humbly suggest that using *no flags at all* will likely result in the fastest compile times. I don't know of any magic `--fast-compile` switch that will make the compiler take less time.

Answer (score 3):

Try -O1, despite it being counter intuitive afaik it *can* speed up compilation compared to -O0. Also check out [ccache](http://ccache.samba.org/)

Comment: ccache does nothing to decrease compile time. It may decrease build time, by _preventing compilation_

Answer (score 3):

You can also try using precompiled headers.

Answer (score 2):

As for GCC, you can try multithreaded compilation (-jX flag, where X is a number of cores you have +1, according to [Reducing compile times](http://www.qtcentre.org/wiki/index.php?title=Reducing_compilation_times#Multithreaded_compilation) article in the Qt Centre).

UPDATE: It seems that I made a mistake: -jX is a 'make' flag, not GCC. So it will improve linking times if you use make-based build system.

Answer (score -3):

If we start with our base line as 'compiling with no flags' there are no flags you can set that will increase the compilation time.

Comment: huh. did you accidentally invert a word?